# Upper bounding a Poisson Process with indicators of exponentials

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Define $E_1,E_2,\ldots, E_i,\ldots E_n$ as i.i.d. exponentials with parameter $\lambda$. These define processes on some interval $[0,\delta]$ (think of $\delta$ as very small, it will come into play later) in the following way

$I_i(t):=\mathbb 1_{\{E_{i}\leq t\}}$.

One could couple each one of the $I_i$'s with a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$ in the following way. Define recursively

$N_i^1 := E_i$, $N_i^k := N_i^{k-1} + \mathcal E^k$,

with $\mathcal E^k\sim \textrm{exp}(\lambda)$. Then $(N_i^j)_{j\geq1}$ are the points of a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$ (essentially, $E_i$ is the first point of the coupled Poisson Process). Call $N_i(t)$ the corresponding Poisson Process. It is clear that the stochastic domination

$I_i(t)\preceq N_i(t)\qquad\forall t\in[0,\delta]$

holds. Indeed,  $N_i$ and $I_i$ share their first jump, but $N_i(\cdot)$ may have more after that in the interval $[0,T]$.

Now, by summing the processes $I_i$'s and the Poisson Processes $N_i(\cdot)$'s over $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we get the stochastic domination

$\sum_{i=1}^nI_i(t) \preceq  \overline N(t)\qquad t\in[0,\delta]$,

where $\overline N(t)$ is a Poisson Process with parameter $n\lambda$.

I am interested in finding the opposite inequality, possibly holding only with high probability. In other words, given the sequence $(I_i(t))_{i\geq1}$, is it possible to couple $\sum_{i=1}^nI_i(t)$ with a Poisson Process $\underline N(\cdot)$ (with some unknown rate, depending on $n$, but which should be less than $n\lambda$) such that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\mathbb P(\sum_{i=1}^nI_i(t)\geq \underline N(t)) = 1$?

Furthermore, the rate $\underline \lambda$ of $\underline N(\cdot)$ should be sufficiently close to $\lambda$, for small $\delta$ (otherwise the trivial choice $\underline \lambda = 0$ would be a solution).

Comment: $\mathcal{E}\sim\exp(\lambda)$? <- doesn't meant $N$ no longer takes  integer values.?

Comment: @Lost1 I am sorry, I probably used confusing notation. $(N_i^j)_{j\geq1}$ are just the points of the process, or the location of the jumps if you will.

Comment: What if you consider just a Poisson process $N_1(t)$ defined over the same probability space as $E_i$'s. The sum of $I_i$'s at $t$ is the number of $E_i$ that are less than $t$. Then you can take $\underline\lambda = \lambda$ as the intensity. Not sure whether you can take $\underline\lambda$ bigger since in such case before the first jump of the sum of $I_i$ there may be the first jump of $\underline N$.

Comment: @Ilya Unfortunately that does not work (if I understood correctly your idea). The Poisson Process might jump multiple times more than $\sum_i I_i$ in the interval $[0,\delta]$.

Comment: not sure I understand it. We have
$$
  M(t) := \sum_{i=1}^n I_(t) = \#\{i\in [1;n]:E_i\leq t\}.
$$
Let us also denote $S_m:=\sum_{i=1}^m E_i$ for $m\leq n$, then
$$
  N(t) := \max\{m \in [1;n]: S_m\leq t\}
$$
is a Poisson process, correct? If $N(t) = k$ then $\sum_{i=1}^k E_i \leq t$ and in particular $E_i\leq t$ for each $i\in [1;k]$, so $M(t)\geq k$. Am I wrong at some point?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think so. $N(t)$ is not a Poisson process (but rather a Poisson process absorbed in $n$). It may happen that $N(t) > n$, for $t< \delta$, then surely $N(t) > M(t)$.

Comment: Unless you use the @ thing I'm not notified of your comments. Ok, if we have a family of iid $\lambda$-exponential r.v. $E'_1,E'_2,\dots$ then $N'(t) = \sup\{m\in \Bbb N: S_m<t\}$ is a Poisson process?

Comment: @Ilya ;) Yes, most definitely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15956/discussion-between-ilya-and-indigo).